# Need to find the Css-selector path

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have the path in the HTML style:

```
    <div class="BaseL">
        <ul class="list">
            <li draggable="true" class="listEntry" id="ItemList.item.0" widgetid="ItemL.item.0" >
```

The code that I have used is:
        driver.findbyElement(By.cssSeelector(".BaseL.list.item.0"))

Its not able to find it by id, tried webdriver.wait (didn't work). But even the cssSelector isnt working, can anyone please help me to find the cssSelector? 
Thanks.

Comment: You have typos in your code to select the element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find your element by Id:

```
driver.findbyElement(By.cssSelector(".ItemList.item.0"));
```

by Class:

```
driver.findbyElement(By.className("#listEntry"));
```

Comment: @IPonik please make correction in your answer. Both line showing css selector with little grammer mistake

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct CSS.

You have to mask the `.` in the li `id` with <kbd>\</kbd>

```
.BaseL .list  #ItemList\.item\.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

```
"div.BaseL>ul.list>li.listEntry[id^='ItemList'][widgetid$='0']"
```

PS: As it is a *draggable* element you have to induce *WebDriverWait*